# FFmpeg: Invalid argument error in complex command( android app)

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to add image overlay on video in my android app. I am getting this error.

*I don't know what is going wrong in my ffmpeg command.*

**My Command:**-

```
["-y","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.mp4","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.jpeg","-filter_complex","[0]crop=720:720[base]","[1]scale=50:50[overl]","[base][overl]overlay=274:305","-preset","ultrafast","-c:a","copy","/storage/emulated/0/Piktale/Sent/Videos/overlay_video4.mp4"]
```

**Error:**-

```
[NULL @ 0xea630600] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[1]scale=50:50[overl]'
[1]scale=50:50[overl]: Invalid argument
```

**Note:**- but they all are working fine individually.

Comment: Try this instead `["-y","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.mp4","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.jpeg","-filter_complex","[0]crop=720:720[base][1]scale=50:50[overl][base][overl]overlay=274:305","-preset","ultrafast","-c:a","copy","/storage/emulated/0/Piktale/Sent/Videos/overlay_video4.mp4"]`

Comment: Thanks HB you saved my time..it is working....